# Absolute url in http.get with angular2

Tags: angular

I have base href set to `/ui/` in my index.html. I try to call `http.get('/api/endpoint')` but angular requests `/ui/api/endpoint` insted. Is there any fix for such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are hosting your app.

Lets say you have this URL:

`http://ROOT_PATH/APP_PATH/ui/home`

You can use 2 options to navigate to a specific point:

1 - `'/api/endpoint'` will resolve to `http://ROOT_PATH/APP_PATH/ui/api/endpoint`

2 - `'./api/endpoint'` will resolve to `http://ROOT_PATH/APP_PATH/ui/home/api/endpoint`

So, for navigating to the APP path you can use `../api/endpoint` that will resolve to `http://ROOT_PATH/APP_PATH/api/endpoint`.

Comment: I would love if it have worked like this, but when I request `'api/endpoint'` it resolves to `http://ROOT_PATH/ui/api/endpoint`. `..` did the trick.

Comment: @Krever, can you vote this answer as the right one? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sure, but the thing about `'api/endpoint'` didn't work and I would like not to mark it as right if it doesnt work. If you leave only the part about `../api/endpoint` I will vote :)

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the third option! That is because is an ajax call and the Angular get the host based on `<base href="/ui">`

Answer (score 1):

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html:

> If the app folder is the application root, as it is for our
>   application, set the href value in index.html exactly as shown:
>
> ```
> <base href="/">
> ```

So when you set:

```
<base href="/ui/">
```

the root url will be: `http://[host]/ui/`