# Subscribing to observable to get data back

Tags: angular, observable

My knowledge on observables are limited, so it might be glaringly like obvious what I am doing wrong here.

On Init on my Angular 2 component, this call happens.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.userService.getUser(+params.get('id')))
        .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    console.info(this.user.id);
}
```

This calls this service method:

```
 getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
        let url = this.baseUserUrl + 'GetUserAsync?id=' + id;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(resp => resp.json() as User);
    };
```

Snippet of the html code where the user object is used

```
<div class="row padding-left">
    <div class="col-sm-6 base-info-container info-box-details">
        <table class="info-box">
            <tr>
                <td>User Id: {{ user.id }}</td>
                <td>Email: {{ user.email }}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resp.json is definitely bringing the data back, but user variable isnt on the component is being set and I have no idea why.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some code from your component HTML too ?

Comment: @t3__rry Edited the post to contain a snippet of it

Comment: Have you tried adding `?` (safe navigator operator: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) as such: `user?.id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to use the safe navigation operator[(Angular docs)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?`: `user?.id`; as while your view is rendered your datas are not fetched yet.

Also in your use case I'd use a `Resolver` to fetch datas before activating 
your component, here's how:

```
// in your route module
const userRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    component: YourComponent,
    resolve: {
       user: UserResolverService
    }
];


// User Resolver Service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from 'your.user.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return 
      this.userService.getUser(route.paramMap.get('id'));
  }

}

// In your user component

constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute) { } 

ngOnInit() {
  // Your snapshot's data matching user you defined in your route resolve
  this.user = this.route.snapshot.data['user'];
}
```

This great article by Thoughtram explains it well: [resolving-route-data-in-angular-2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Hi,So I've done all that however, I get a 'URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute' error on load.

Is it something to do with my service code?

Comment: Never seen this one but I've found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234735/absolute-url-in-http-get-with-angular2